# Insert custom Button inside Gridview pager

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to insert a control inside Gridview pager. The Control appears successfuly but it assign it under the previous control as you can see in the picture.

[image]

I am adding with the following code.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(ImageButton1);
}
```

What i want is to assign the Save Answers button next to Previous button and not below. Any help pls ?

Comment: No i do not have a template. I only have EnablePaging True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
{
    Table pagerTable = (e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as Table);
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    row = pagerTable.Rows[0];
    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
    cell1.Controls.Add(ImageButton1);

    row.Cells.AddAt(1,cell1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a pager style in your gridview:

```
<PagerStyle Width="100%" />
```

Why don't you create a pagertemplate with your button inside ?
It will be easier for you to define the positions of each button.

```
 <asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
        datasourceid="CustomersSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="false"
        emptydatatext="No data available." 
        allowpaging="true" 
        runat="server">
...
        <pagerstyle Width="100%"/>

      </asp:gridview>
```

Comment: The "previous" and "Next" button are auto generate, isn't it ? So you need to create a template for the pager it is the only way.